# How to add an int parameter to a function in clang using libTooling?

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I'm trying to implement a source-to-source compiler using Clang. How can I add an integer parameter to a specific function (e.g., identified by its name)?

For example, the original function definition is:

```
int foo(int a)
{
    return a+1;
}
```

The transformed code should be:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b+1;
}
```

Comment: You want to do *exactly* this? That doesn't make much sense; technically you can do with a "replace *this* function-body-string by *that* string".  I can understand adding an extra parameter; but to *which* function(s) [*just* foo? unlikely]?   And, how do you want to modify the function body to *use* that extra parameter? Surely you aren't assuming that every function to be enhanced has only a single return statement?  I don't think you've defined the problem well enough (at least not "interestingly" enough).

Comment: I simplified my problem. The point is that if I know how to add a parameter to the function foo, I know how to solve my real problem. It's not easy to me because I don't know how to change the function type and also once the parameters of the function are already set, it seems not possible to add parameters.

Comment: It is still unclear what you want to do.  Add a parameter... which one? what type? where in paramer list?  For which function declaration? What do you want to do with the function calls in the same compilation unit?  Other compilation units?  Without a clear characterization of the task, you're not going to get a lot of useful advice.